# Determinisric AES-CTR in Java BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I have been using [aes-js](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js) in Node to encrypt/decrypt using AES counter mode.

As you can see in the example, I'm using it without padding and I can specify which block (0 in this case) I want to start with.

```
var aesCTR = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(keyBytes, new aesjs.Counter(0));
var encryptedBytes = aesCTR.encrypt(plaintextBytes);
```

---

I wanted to reproduce the same behavior above in Java. I'm using [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/) like the example below.

```
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(msgBytes);
```

But this implementation doesn't seem to be outputting the sames values as the one above. Plus it seems to increment the counter automatically each run (undesirable behavior in this case).

Is there a way to match the Node JS implementation using Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the same behaviour if you provide an IV / initial ctr value that is all zero e.g:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
Arrays.fill(iv, (byte)0);    

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(msgBytes);
```

The way it is set up in your code, a random IV is generated every time you call `init()`.

BTW, if you omit `BC`, you will get the stock AES implementation